# Simple powershell success or fail log

Tags: powershell, error-handling, powershell-3.0

I'm looking for the easiest way to write the success or failure of a scheduled script to a csv file. I am not looking for a way to log the error or reason of failure just a simple "Succes/Failure". For this reason i'm not trying to fix/log non-terminating errors.

I thought the easiest way to put every script in a

```
    try {
Write-Host "test"
    }
    catch{
Code to write to csv here 
    }
```

Block where I write to a csv file in the Catch part. Is there a better/easier way to do this or is this the right way to go?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: `catch` is only entered in case of terminating errors, requiring to pass `-ErrorAction Stop` or set `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'`. You may want to add a `finally` block that checks the `$Error` variable to collect non-terminating errors too.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the input, but basically the only thing I want to log is if the script was executed without a terminating error.

Comment: @JosefZ done. But won't really add a lot since I meant in general and nog for a specific script.

Comment: From my experience, there's no "*easy*" way to go about this without some control of flow. So you can't just build off of that.

Comment: @Abraham Zinala if that's true om open for suggestions. What would be the minimal way with the control of flow you mention?

Comment: If by failure you mean a terminating error then yes, try catch is the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Continuing from my comment. . .*

Honestly, this really depends on the situation, i.e. what is you're trying to accomplish. So, let's make up a scenario of querying a computer for some basic info:

```
Function Get-SystemInfo {
    Param (
        
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false,
                   ValueFromPipeline=$true,
                   ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    
    )
    Begin {

        $ErrorActionPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'

    }
    Process {

        foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) 
        {
            try {

                # attempt cim session with -EA Stop to not allow it to go
                # any further and we can calculate the results.
                $CIMSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $Computer -ErrorAction Stop

                $Status     = $true

                # Perform the actual queries
                $CS = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_COmputerSystem -CimSession $CIMSession
                $BS = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_BIOS -CimSession $CIMSession 

                # evaluate against the returned objects
                $UserName     = if ($CS.UserName -eq $null) { 'No User Logged in' } else { $CS.UserName }
                $Manufacturer = if ($CS.Manufacturer -eq $null) { 'N/a' } else { $CS.Manufacturer }
                $Model        = if ($CS.Model -eq $null) { 'N/a' } else { $CS.Model }
                $SerialNumber = if ($BS.SerialNumber -eq $null) { 'N/a' } else { $BS.SerialNumber }

            }
            catch {

                # Set the variables to $null
                $Status       = $false

                $UserName     = $null
                $Manufacturer = $null
                $Model        = $null
                $SerialNumber = $null

            }
            finally {

                # Output the filled variables
                [PSCustomObject] @{

                    ComputerName = $Computer
                    Connected    = $Status
                    UserLoggedIn = $UserName
                    Manufacturer = $Manufacturer
                    Model        = $Model
                    SerialNumber = $SerialNumber 

                }

            }

        }

    }

    End {
        
        # cleanup
        
        # some people argue this should be in the finally block
        # to disconnect any machine, but looking at this from both
        # sides, they both have pros/cons.    
        Get-CimSession | Remove-CimSession

    }

}
```

... the biggest take-away from this quick function, is the `-ErrorAction Stop` while trying to create a *CIM* session. This is where looking at the bigger picture comes into play. If you are unable to connect to the computer, why bother continuing? This includes getting an echo reply from a quick ping since that doesn't dictate that you can connect to the remote PC just because you got a reply.

The rest is the `if`, and `else` statements that handle the *light* work evaluating against the returned objects for more control over the output.

Results would be:

```
PS C:\Users\Abraham> Get-SystemInfo

ComputerName : OER
Connected    : True
UserLoggedIn : Abraham
Manufacturer : LENOVO
Model        : 22251
SerialNumber : 55555555




PS C:\Users\Abraham> Get-SystemInfo -ComputerName BogusComputerName

ComputerName : BogusComputerName
Connected    : False
UserLoggedIn : 
Manufacturer : 
Model        : 
SerialNumber :
```